# Import txt file into Modal body

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have the file Contact.txt imported in my project with the

```
id='contact'
```

The uploading part I do with the following function:

```
var loadFile = function ('./data/en/Contact.txt', 'contact', true) {
    var allText;
    var titleText;

    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", source, true);

    txtFile.onload = function () {
        if (txtFile.readyState === txtFile.DONE) {
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {
                allText = txtFile.responseText.split('\n');
                if (hasOnlyTitle == false) {
                    //selects the first line from the txt file, in our case the title
                    titleText = allText[0];

                    //removes the first line from txt file
                    allText.splice(0, 1).join('\n');
                    document.getElementById(targetId + "Title").innerHTML = titleText;
                }
                var finalText = allText.join('<br />');
            }
            document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = finalText;
        }
    };
    txtFile.send(null);
}
```

The uploading function I have tested separated and it works...

I have tried to import the text from the file into the body of a modal component, but it just won't display anything...

Here is the html part:

```
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <p id="contact"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the js file:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("info");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you importing text file? And what errors you have in console?

Comment: @AntihypeBird I have no errors in console... I will update the question with the upload function of the txt file

Comment: Have you defined `hasOnlyTitle` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes, it is defined. I set the value to "true" because I have just 1 word (for testing)

Answer (score 2):

On your code you never load the content of the file. Assuming that you have the file on the server, you can load the content when the page is open adding something like this to the jquery document ready:

```
$.get('/contact.txt', function(data) {
    $("#contact").text(data)
});
```

or use the same function inside the btn.onclick. This will be slower, and the information can take some time to load. So it's better to load the information on document load/ready.

This way, when the users open's the modal, the contact information will be quickly available.

Comment: still not works... :( Ps: I have edited the post with the uploading function that I use for importing the txt file

Comment: I would not suggest a jQuery solution when OP is using native JS. I would also not mix `jQuery` and `$` for no reason.

Comment: @DanFromGermany your are right. Are just a quick example. making a console.log of the finaltext before send it to the modal , you get what you want? And the tiitle works?

Comment: @andre_vieira I've tried to put a console.log just when the modal starts and it displays the message. I think it's just a problem with displaying that text into the body...

Comment: @andre_vieira I've tried to add the code directly into btn.onclick but it still doesn't show anything... I don't have any errors either

Comment: using the inpect element, try to see if the contact have the text. If yes, than is a css problem. It's weird